# How to access SOAP web services in Android

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I tried to access soap Ws using httpPost;this my code

```
          HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(WebService Url);
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
        httpPost.addHeader("Host", HostName);


        //get from the getflashinfo method;
        String soapRequestXml=getFlashInfo(0);

        Log.d("Message12", soapRequestXml);

        try 
        {
            StringEntity se=new StringEntity(soapRequestXml, HTTP.UTF_8);
            se.setContentType("text/xml");
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            HttpClient hC=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse reponse=hC.execute(httpPost);
            Log.d("Message12", response.toString());
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Second Function

```
String getFlashInfo(int target) 
    {
        String sHeaderRequest="<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\">"+
         "<s:Header>"  +
     "<a:Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://tempuri.org/IFlashInfoService/GetFlashInfo</a:Action>"  +
     "<a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo>"  +
     "<a:To s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">URL</a:To>" + 
     "</s:Header>"  +
     "<s:Body xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">"  +
     "<GetIdTargetRequest xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" ; 

    String sHeaderRequest1;
    if (target > 0)
    {
        sHeaderRequest1="<IdTarget>"+" "+target+" "
        +"</IdTarget>";
    }
    else
    {
        sHeaderRequest1="<IdTarget>0</IdTarget>";
    }
    sHeaderRequest=sHeaderRequest+sHeaderRequest1;
    sHeaderRequest=sHeaderRequest+"</GetIdTargetRequest>";

    sHeaderRequest=sHeaderRequest+"</s:Body>";
    sHeaderRequest=sHeaderRequest+"</s:Envelope>";

    Log.d("Message12", sHeaderRequest);

    return sHeaderRequest;
}
```

I got Null Pointer exception when try to log the reponse message

I used Ksop library with

```
           got some kind of xmlparse error and unknown source exception
```

Please Help me

Regards,
Kariyachan

Comment: Take a look at SOAP library for android http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

Comment: thanks for the reply I used with that library. but it end up with error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting a video tutorial, this might help

http://www.vimeo.com/9633556

Happy Coding!